# Scala class extends Trait

Tags: scala, class, traits

When trying to extend an class with a trait with concrete definition like so

```
trait logmsg
{
  printmsg(msg : String)  = println(msg)
}

class DimensionUtils extends logmsg {
  printmsg("hello")
}
```

why does the repl give the following error:

```
**error**
defined trait logmsg
<console>:16: error: not found: value printmsg
          printmsg("hello")
```

Comment: this code is correct. I'm guessing you are pasting the code into the REPL, and the problem will go away if you move the first `{` onto the same line as `trait logmsg`, to prevent the REPL from taking `trait logmsg` by itself as a complete definition. this is one of the reasons Scala programmers never put `{` on a line by itself. (the other is semicolon inference.)

Comment: Moreover looking for scala style guide You should have trait starting with capital letter. In 90% situation put the parenthesis in the same line, not a new line. Remove all necessary lines. Your code can have 7 lines with the same information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Code is correct, I tried in eclipse editor by creating a Scala project, getting an answer as "hello"
here is the code which runs.

```
object StackQ extends App {
  val obj = new DimensionUtils
}

trait log_msg {
  def printmsg(msg: String) = println(msg)
}

class DimensionUtils extends log_msg {
  printmsg("hello")
}
```